# docker-compose clearing database each time i am building container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My Dockerfile

```
    FROM python:3.8
    ARG index_url

    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    WORKDIR /usr/src/antiquely

    COPY ./ /usr/src/antiquely

    RUN apt-get -y update
    RUN apt-get -y install python-mysqldb
    RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev

    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


    CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

docker-compose file

```
    version: "3"

    services:
    web:
        container_name: antiquely
        build: ./
        # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        command: "bash -c 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'"
        working_dir: /usr/src/antiquely
        ports:
        - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src/antiquely
        links:
        - db

    #mysql
    db:
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "baby"
        MYSQL_USER: "soubhagya"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "Thinkonce"
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "Thinkonce"
        volumes:
        - /var/run/mysqld
        ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

I have my docker and docker-compose it is building and running properly but each time i am building it is createing new database
so clearing old database data

Is there any way to handle this ?

Please have a look.

Comment: Because you did not define Volume correctly. This is the correct way. `/var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld`

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain data between runs of *any* docker container, you must provide a volume mount.

You can usually see this type of instructions in the official page for the image you are using. For example, from the [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) image on DockerHub:

> The -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql part of the command mounts the /my/own/datadir directory from the underlying host system as /var/lib/mysql inside the container, where MySQL by default will write its data files.

(Look for the "Where to Store Data" section).

In your case, you should add the volume instructions to your `db` service definition in your docker-compose:

```yaml
db:
  # ...
  volumes:
  - /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
```